# How can I reduce the gap between my content and header?

Tags: html, css

Here's a js fiddle of the problem: http://bit.ly/Zd8JAU

I'm trying to place a header with a logo and a centred title at the top of the page. The idea is to center the title to the page itself and not within the gap left to the right of the logo, if that makes sense?

So I floated the logo over the top of the title and then altered the position of the logo shifting it upwards (as otherwise it insists on going beneath the title). The problem is this then creates a gap, which cascades down the page and I'd have to somehow shift everything up by the hight of the logo, and I really don't want to have to do that.

So is there a better way to get my logo positioned to the left of the title without creating gaps anywhere and without it causing an off-set on the text in the title?

EDIT: updated the fiddle to be clearer what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I've solved this by using an extra div behind the title, which I use for the title's background and making the title's div shift left with a negative margin, before I centre the title text. However, it's not a very nice solution to use lots of extra mark-up. Can anyone do any better? http://bit.ly/WuHi1s

Answer (score 0):

Yes, consider using a CSS background for your logo as part of your NAV element, which makes it easier to pad your text and position the image without interference.